# How to make tojson() filter in Jinja2 output Unicode instead of escape sequences?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, unicode, jinja2

My template is used for JS

```
let SETTINGS = {{settings|tojson(4)}};
```

My settings is a dict `{'name': 'Russian name Саша', 'id': 12345}`. If I render it, i get:

```
let SETTINGS = {
    "name": "Russian name \u0421\u0430\u0448\u0430",
    "id": 12345
}
```

I need to get non-escaped unicode characters. The same way I can do in python using

```
json.dumps(data, encure_ascii=False)
```

But `tojson()` filter accepts only one parameter (indent).

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to supply rest parameters to `tojson()` filter.

Starting with Jinja 2.9 [policies](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#policies) can be configured on the environment which influence how filters and other template constructs behave. It can be done by changing some keys of policies attribute.

For your case there is `json.dumps_kwargs` policy. This is what you have to do:

```
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.policies['json.dumps_kwargs']['ensure_ascii'] = False
```

This modified environment will not escape unicode symbols.